# How do I get this response interceptor to work in Angular?

Tags: angular, response, angular-http-interceptors

I have the following code for an HttpInterceptor but I can't get the response interceptor part of it to work:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private user: UserService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      const modified = req.clone();
      return next.handle(modified)
        .pipe(
          tap(event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
              if (event.status === 401) {
                this.user.logout();
              }
            }
          })
        );
    } else {
      const modified = req.clone({setHeaders: {'Authorization': 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('token')}});
      return next.handle(modified)
        .pipe(
          tap(event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
              if (event.status === 401) {
                this.user.logout();
              }
            }
          })
        );
    }

  }
}
```

The part where it is handling the response isn't working. Basically I am trying to check if a 401 was returned and then log the user out automatically if there was a 401.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `catch` to specifically catch the error response.

RxJS 5 and below (or RxJS 6+ with `rxjs-compact` installed for compatibility):

```
next.handle(modified).catch(errorResponse => { 
  // do something
})
```

RxJS 6+ without `rxjs-compact`:

`catch` was removed because it is a reserved keyword in JS.

```
next.handle(modified).pipe(
  catchError(errorResponse => { 
  // do something
  }))
```

Or, if you still want to use `pipe` and `tap`, `tap` has three optional parameters: next callback, error callback and complete callback.

```
next.handle(modified).pipe(
  tap(
    event => { 
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse)
        console.log('request succeeded');
    },
    error => {
      if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        console.log('request failed');
      }
    }
  ));
```

Comment: @Jasonmate I like how concise catch is, but next.handle(modified) is an observable, and catch doesn't exist on the Observable type (at least that's what my IDE is telling me).

Comment: @Jasonca1 `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';` rxjs/Observable with the capital O. See if this works.

Comment: Rxjs has many modules with different casting of these objects. 'rxjs/Observable' imports a partial observable (you need to manually import some operators). I believe 'rxjs/Rx' imports something like the full Observable - which significantly increases bundle size. Not recommended. If you import the full Observable in different modules you can see a new (and significantly large) bundle created specifically for this. And TBH I have no idea what Observable object 'rxjs' imports...

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'; does not do anything. I still can't attach catch to the handle method call.

Comment: It's fine ;) Can you post your RxJS dependency versions? I gather you have RxJS 6+ without rxjs-compact, so `catchError` *should* work... doesn't it? o_O